# SQL Server mapped User to Login with DB owned same Login

Tags: sql-server, authentication

I want to create SQL login and user that user mapped to login. And then my DB owned by login. But I get this error:

> "The proposed new database owner is mapped as user in this database"

In fact I want to have login with public server role and also have user mapped to that login to restrict access to my DB. How can I do that?

Comment: Just so I understand what you're looking to do, you want to create a user in the database but can't because of the error message you posted above. Is that correct?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I owned DB by Login and also want to mapped Login to user. It was my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

As you've discovered, each login can only be mapped to one user in a given database (informally, think of there being a uniqueness constraint on the sid column in sys.database_principals). To find out which login yours is mapped to, try the following:

```
select d.name as [UserName]
from sys.database_principals as d
join sys.server_principals as s
   on d.sid = s.sid
where s.name = '<your login name here>';
```

I suspect that in your particular case, the user name is going to come back as 'dbo'. Regardless though, at this point you have two options:

1. Change the user's name with `alter user [<username from above>] with login = [<new user name>]`.
2. Leave everything as it is.

In the case of number 1, you're changing which login maps to that particular user in the database. If you're doing this with the dbo user, keep in mind that that login will now lose all permissions that it had. So, if an application relies on that login, keep that in mind.

In the case of #2, perhaps everything is as it should be. In which case there's nothing to do.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue when creating a new database in **MS SQL Server 2012**.

The issue was that the user that I was assigning to the new database is already programmed to be assigned to every **new database** that is to be created.

So it was a duplicate operation by me when I tried assigning the user again to a new database.

All I had to do was to cancel the operation and create a new database without specifying a user and this worked fine.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**